# VBA - Loop Pivot Table Filtering Extract

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code which applies a filter to a Pivot Table, then specific data is copied from the PivotTable and the filters are removed.. The issue is, this one block of code is used 22 times, the sub is waaaay too long.

Here is the code I have with only ONE of the blocks:

```
    Option Explicit

        Sub FilterPivotTable()

        Dim rLastCell As Range
        Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
        Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
        Dim LastRow1 As Long
        Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PivotTable")
        Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")
        Dim rowCount As Long

            LastRow1 = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1)

            'Microsoft Windows
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False

            ws1.PivotTables("P1").ManualUpdate = True

            ws1.PivotTables("P1").PivotFields(" Vulnerability Name").ClearAllFilters

    '---------------Block Starts Here---------------

            ws1.PivotTables("P1").PivotFields(" Vulnerability Name").PivotFilters. _
            Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:="Microsoft Windows"

            ws1.PivotTables("P1").ManualUpdate = False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True

            With ws1.PivotTables(1).TableRange1
                Set rLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                Set PvtTbl = Worksheets("PivotTable").PivotTables("P1")
                rLastCell.Copy

                With ws2

                    .Cells(LastRow1 + 2, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                    .Range("$B$2").Value = "Microsoft Windows"

                    rowCount = PvtTbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
                    .Range("$D$2") = rowCount - 1

                End With

            End With

            ws1.PivotTables("P1").PivotFields(" Vulnerability Name").ClearAllFilters

'---------------Block Ends Here---------------

        End Sub
```

This block of code is repeated 22 times throughout this sub, each time only changing the vulnerability name i.e. Changing **'Microsoft Windows'** to **'Adobe'** and then changing the Cell Reference for where the data is to be copied to the Summary Sheet.

I am hoping to rather have one block of code that loops through the vulnerability names instead of having 22 different blocks of code performing the same function.

This is what the Pivot Table Structure looks like:

[image]

The filter is done under the rows block and done on Vulnerability Name

Comment: So you are trying to change  ws1.PivotTables("P1").PivotFields(" Vulnerability Name").PivotFilters. _
            Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:="Microsoft Windows"  ?

Comment: @QHarr yes, trying to change "Microsoft Windows" to "Adobe Reader" as well as in the With statement it appears again with specific cell reference - that also needs to be have an increment for each filter.. So MS Windows would be pasted in the first row of the first 3 columns, then adobe in the next row, then MS Office in the next and so on

Comment: Do you intend to loop all items within the pivottfield? That would be the obvious thing to do even if you are only after a few items.

Comment: Also, be careful of With statements within With statements.

Comment: I would have liked to loop through all the items in the pivotfield, but unfortunately there's just too many so our focus is solely on the 22 that we need. @QHarr

Comment: What layout format is your pivottable? Design > Report > Tabular? And are subtotals showing

Comment: So the 22 you want can be in a string array that you loop and then Value1:= myArray(counter)    ........

Comment: You need to copy the entire contents to a different `Sub` and pass the relevant parameters, such as `Sub PivotFieldsLoop (AppName as String)` and you call this Sub by passing `"Microsoft Windows"`, the same for all other related objects and parameters

Comment: You also seem to be using ws1 to determine lastRow but are pasting to ws2?

Comment: @ShaiRado Can they not loop and apply filter instead or are you saying that they can still loop and pass the current loop index to a sub that performs the copy paste?

Comment: @QHarr the second option

Comment: @QHarr The format is the default layout, not exactly sure which one that is.. There are subtotals showing yes. There are tow columns: When you collapse the first column it has Vulnerability Nam > IP Address > DNS Name > OS. The second column is just the Count of IP addresses (subtotals). Yes I was thinking to have a string array that loops through it.

Comment: @QHarr I corrected the code in my macro after I pasted the sample here - this is with reference to the lastRow. I have updated the sample here too.

Comment: I have written a stab in the dark answer which may or may not move you forwards. I suspect you might want to set last row using column C or worksheet 2. But I am uncertain of a few things.

Comment: @ShaiRado Thank you for assisting with this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a punt in the dark I'm afraid

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterPivotTable()

    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim PvtTbl As PivotTable
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("PivotTable")
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Summary")

    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim LastRow1 As Long
    Dim pvtField As PivotField

    Set PvtTbl = ws1.PivotTables("P1")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set pvtField = PvtTbl.PivotFields(" Vulnerability Name") 'extend etc as required

    Dim myArr()
    myArr = Array("Microsoft Windows", "Adobe Reader", "Other")

    'PvtTbl.ManualUpdate = False

    Dim i As Long

    For i = LBound(myArr) To UBound(myArr)

        pvtField.ClearAllFilters
        pvtField.PivotFilters. _
        Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:=myArr(i)

        With ws1.PivotTables(1).TableRange1
            Set rLastCell = .Cells(.Rows.count, .Columns.count) 'grand total?
        End With

        With ws2
            LastRow1 = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.count, 3).End(xlUp).row
            rLastCell.Copy
            .Cells(LastRow1 + 1, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
            .Cells(LastRow1 + 1, 2).Value = myArr(i)
            rowCount = PvtTbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.count
            .Cells(LastRow1 + 1, 4) = rowCount - 1
        End With

    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    'PvtTbl.ManualUpdate = False
End Sub
```

Comment: you are a GENIUS! This is working great! Wow. There are three small things I just want to find out: 1) On the summary sheet, after every paste, it skips a row then pastes the next filtered data 2) The sheet doesnt update while im on it, I need to click on another sheet and when I go back to the summary sheet, it has been updated 3) Your comment of "grand total" that is correct

Comment: I will update answer now. For 1) you just change  .Cells(LastRow1 + 2, 3)  to  .Cells(LastRow1 + 1, 3) etc

Comment: Tbh this could be coded better as Mr Rado has pointed out. So I have changed point 1 for you. Point 2 I am not sure why. I have temp commented out your two lines for PvtTbl.ManualUpdate which you can uncomment again if makes no difference.

Comment: thank you this is perfect. The lines you commented out didn't work, but its fine. Im happy with this and really appreciate your help! Thank you :)

Comment: Happy days then